# How to find regex in referer url?

Tags: regex, nginx

To deny some spammers who abuse valid referes to attack certain urls, I'd need a regexp rule to deny all `google.*` referes to `/some/target/url`

Here is what I've tried:

```
location  ^~  /some/target/url {
if ($http_referer ~ (.*)google(.*))
 {  return 400;
     }
}
```

UPDATE:
What I want to avoid in the rule above are all google.* referers, e.g.

```
google.com
google.de
google.co.uk
google.jp
...
```

But, based on access.log, the above directive (and others that I've tried) do not work. So I appreciate your help.

Comment: Give us some examples of what you want to avoid. And what does "not work" mean. Your current regex means any symbols before and after the google, hence, "asdasdgoogleasdasd" is also invalid.

Answer (score 0):

No need for the parenthesis, so you can have:

```
~ google
```

to be case-insensitive:

```
~* google
```

Then you'll probably want to make it more robust, e.g., to avoid `http://www.your.com/google`.